# Combine rows in a JSON-like type on-the-fly

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by

Given the following sample data:

| name | label_id | label_prop1 | label_prop2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | L1 | 100 | abc |
| foo | L2 | 300 | def |
| bar | L1 | 200 | ghi |

How could I change my query so that it makes it into 2 rows, where label are combined into a JSON like object?

| name | labels |
| --- | --- |
| foo | { "L1" : { "label_prop1": 100, "label_prop2": "abc" }, "L2" : { "label_prop1": 300, "label_prop2": "def" }} |
| bar | { "L1" : { "label_prop1": 200, "label_prop2": "ghi" } |

Might be pushing what you can do in SQL but it would nice and probably quicker to not have to do this aggregating in the application code.

I'll take other suggestions that come close! E.g.:

| name | labels |
| --- | --- |
| foo | [{"label_id": "L1", "label_prop1": 100, "label_prop2": "abc" },{"label_id": "L2", "label_prop1": 300, "label_prop2": "def" }] |
| bar | [{"label_id": "L1", "label_prop1": 200, "label_prop2": "ghi" }] |

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to solve this problem is to use:

- `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT`, to generate your "*label_prop*" values
- `JSON_OBJECT_AGG`, to generate your aggregated object with labels

```
SELECT name, 
       JSON_OBJECT_AGG(
           label_id, JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                         'label_prop1', label_prop1,
                         'label_prop2', label_prop2
           )
       ) AS labels
FROM tab
GROUP BY name;
```

| name | json_object_agg |
| --- | --- |
| bar | {"L1":{"label_prop1":200,"label_prop2":"ghi"}} |
| foo | {"L1":{"label_prop1":100,"label_prop2":"abc"},"L2":{"label_prop1":300,"label_prop2":"def"}} |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cyxkYKnGdXbywN5ZaUWcGW/0).

---

If you prefer your second output, you can instead use:

- `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT`, to generate your combined data infos
- `JSON_AGG`, to aggregate your split json into an array of jsons

```
SELECT name, 
       JSON_AGG(
           JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
               'label_id', label_id,
               'label_prop1', label_prop1,
               'label_prop2', label_prop2
           )
       ) AS labels
FROM tab
GROUP BY name;
```

| name | labels |
| --- | --- |
| bar | [{"label_id":"L1","label_prop1":200,"label_prop2":"ghi"}] |
| foo | [{"label_id":"L1","label_prop1":100,"label_prop2":"abc"},{"label_id":"L2","label_prop1":300,"label_prop2":"def"}] |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cyxkYKnGdXbywN5ZaUWcGW/1).

Comment: Thanks again. Postgres if  awesome! Didn't know about db-fiddle.com either, pretty cool!